# SQL: Combine columns to specific datetime and cast to UTC

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL. I want to convert three columns to datetime in sql.

My data looks like:

```
DAY (DATE)     HOUR (NUMBER)     HALFHOUR (NUMBER)
21.04.22       11                22
21.04.22       11                23
21.04.22       12                24
21.04.22       12                25
21.04.22       13                26
21.04.22       13                27
....
```

I need to combine each row to the following specific format, in one column:

```
2022-04-21T13:30:00.00Z
```

Moreover, it should be converted from an utc time where data comes from (like UTC+3) to UTC+0 automatically.

How do I do this? I googled a lot, but cant do it.

Thanks :)

Comment: why the output is 2022-04-21T13:30:00.00Z. This is for which row ?

Comment: it needs to be this way for an interface. its a combination of the columns in my database ive shown above. In this case, its the last row

Comment: @dev.niho Is it fixed that it is coming from UTC+3 always?

Comment: no. it changes with summer- and wintertime in germany

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is:

```
SELECT T1.*,
TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP(DAY||' '||HOUR||':'||HALFHOUR, 'DD.MM.RR HH24:MI'), 'Europe/Berlin') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff2"Z"') as time_utc
FROM T1;
```

> **[TO_TIMESTAMP:](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm)**
>
> TO_TIMESTAMP converts char of CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or NVARCHAR2
> datatype to a value of TIMESTAMP datatype.
> Syntax is:
>
> ```
> TO_TIMESTAMP( string1 [, format_mask] ['nlsparam'] )
> ```
>
> [**FROM_TZ:**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions059.htm)
>
> In Oracle Database, the FROM_TZ() function converts a timestamp value
> and a time zone to a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE value. Pass the
> timestamp value and the time zone as two separate arguments, and the
> function returns them as a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE value.
> Syntax is :
>
> ```
> FROM_TZ(timestamp_value, time_zone_value)
> ```
>
> time_zone_value all possible values an be found out using the below query:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES;
> ```

The output generated using above two functions is the time in the germany time-zone and is converted to UTC time zone using the **[" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' "](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/expressions006.htm)**

Then using **[TO_CHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm)** it is converted to the required format.

You can see the working sample example at the below link:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b030170a2c5536b4f80f1287bbfe4aca